# Gauss Jordan Elimination different answers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have a question regarding Gauss Jordan Elimination. I have this matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}2&1&5&0\\1&0&-3&1\\7&2&2&1\end{bmatrix}

So at the start I will switch R1 with R2, like that is for me the most logical thing to do. But if I run the matrix through http://www.gregthatcher.com/Mathematics/GaussJordan.aspx  They don't do it this way and get a different answer than I do. My answer is

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&7\\0&1&0&-24\\0&0&1&2\end{bmatrix}

and that is wrong. The answer should be

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&-5\\0&1&0&20\\0&0&1&-2\end{bmatrix}

Shouldn't I get the same answer in the end no matter how I do the reduction? I don't see anything wrong with my method. Can someone check my answer with my method ( start by switching R1 and R2) ?

Comment: You can do that switch, and you should get the same answer as the other one. You must have made some computational mistake.

Comment: yeah, ok. It was an stupid error in my computation. Hard to spot really .Thanks anyway :)